# Are there any different ways to have Python GTK end itself?

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm fairly new to PyGTK and have been trying to write an automatically updating picture slideshow program. So far it does exactly what I need it to, but with one problem. It runs by taking images in the directory it is saved in, and then running through them on a timer. When it reaches the last picture it's supposed to reset and run again so you can add new pictures at any time without stopping it. And it does that, but opens new windows instead of resetting properly. So if it runs three times, there are three windows open, and it can strain a computer fairly fast. Does anyone know a way to get around this?

The code's fairly lengthy but here it is for reference:

```
import os

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import glib

def is_image(filename):
if not os.path.isfile(filename):
    return False
for suffix in ['.jpg', '.png', '.bmp', '.gif']:
    if filename.lower().endswith(suffix):
        return True
return False

def resizeToFit(image, frame, aspect=True, enlarge=False):
if aspect:
    return scaleToFit(image, frame, enlarge)
else:
    return stretchToFit(image, frame, enlarge)

def scaleToFit(image, frame, enlarge=False):
image_width, image_height = image
frame_width, frame_height = frame
image_aspect = float(image_width) / image_height
frame_aspect = float(frame_width) / frame_height
if not enlarge:
    max_width = min(frame_width, image_width)
    max_height = min(frame_height, image_height)
else:
    max_width = frame_width
    max_height = frame_height
if frame_aspect > image_aspect:
    height = max_height
    width = int(height * image_aspect)
else:
    width = max_width
    height = int(width / image_aspect)
return (width, height)

def stretchToFit(image, frame, enlarge=False):
image_width, image_height = image
frame_width, frame_height = frame
if not enlarge:
    width = min(frame_width, image_width)
    height = min(frame_height, image_height)
else:
    width = frame_width
    height = frame_height
return (width, height)


class ResizableImage(gtk.DrawingArea):

def __init__(self, aspect=True, enlarge=False,
        interp=gtk.gdk.INTERP_NEAREST, backcolor=None, max=(1600,1200)):
    super(ResizableImage, self).__init__()
    self.pixbuf = None
    self.aspect = aspect
    self.enlarge = enlarge
    self.interp = interp
    self.backcolor = backcolor
    self.max = max
    self.connect('expose_event', self.expose)
    self.connect('realize', self.on_realize)

def on_realize(self, widget):
    if self.backcolor is None:
        color = gtk.gdk.Color()
    else:
        color = gtk.gdk.Color(*self.backcolor)
    self.window.set_background(color)

def expose(self, widget, event):
    self.context = self.window.cairo_create()
    self.context.rectangle(
        event.area.x, event.area.y,
        event.area.width, event.area.height)
    self.context.clip()
    self.draw(self.context)
    return False

def draw(self, context):
    rect = self.get_allocation()
    x, y = rect.x, rect.y
    parent = self.get_parent()
    if parent:
        offset = parent.get_allocation()
        x -= offset.x
        y -= offset.y
    if self.backcolor:
        context.rectangle(x, y, rect.width, rect.height)
        context.set_source_rgb(*self.backcolor)
        context.fill_preserve()
    if not self.pixbuf:
        return
    width, height = resizeToFit(
        (self.pixbuf.get_width(), self.pixbuf.get_height()),
        (rect.width, rect.height),
        self.aspect,
        self.enlarge)
    x = x + (rect.width - width) / 2
    y = y + (rect.height - height) / 2
    context.set_source_pixbuf(
        self.pixbuf.scale_simple(width, height, self.interp), x, y)
    context.paint()

def set_from_pixbuf(self, pixbuf):
    width, height = pixbuf.get_width(), pixbuf.get_height()
    if not self.max or (width < self.max[0] and height < self.max[1]):
        self.pixbuf = pixbuf
    else:
        width, height = resizeToFit((width, height), self.max)
        self.pixbuf = pixbuf.scale_simple(
            width, height,
            gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
    self.invalidate()

def set_from_file(self, filename):
    self.set_from_pixbuf(gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(filename))

def invalidate(self):
    self.queue_draw()

class DemoGtk:

SECONDS_BETWEEN_PICTURES = 1
FULLSCREEN = True
WALK_INSTEAD_LISTDIR = True

def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window()
    self.window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
    self.window.set_title('Slideshow')
    self.image = ResizableImage( True, True, gtk.gdk.INTERP_BILINEAR)
    self.image.show()
    self.window.add(self.image)
    self.load_file_list()
    self.window.show_all()
    if self.FULLSCREEN:
        self.window.fullscreen()
    glib.timeout_add_seconds(self.SECONDS_BETWEEN_PICTURES, self.on_tick)
    self.display()

def load_file_list(self):
    self.files = []
    self.index = 0
    if self.WALK_INSTEAD_LISTDIR:
        for directory, sub_directories, files in os.walk('.'):
            for filename in files:
                if is_image(filename):
                    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                    self.files.append(filepath)
    else:
        for filename in os.listdir('.'):
            if is_image(filename):
                self.files.append(filename)
    print "Images:", self.files

def display(self):
    if 0 <= self.index < len(self.files):
        self.image.set_from_file(self.files[self.index])
        return True
    else:
        return False

def on_tick(self):
    self.index += 1
    if self.index >= len(self.files):
        self.index = 0
        gtk.main_quit()
    return self.display()


    return self.display()
if __name__ == "__main__":
gui = DemoGtk()
gtk.main()

while True:
execfile("slideshowtest.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, it would be sufficient to execute `self.load_file_list()` instead of `gtk.main_quit()` in the `on_tick(self)` method.

However, I think your program can be simplified quite a bit. This does basically the same and needs half the lines of code (it's for PyGObject but it can be changed to pygtk):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, GLib, Gdk
import sys, os

class ImageWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self, fullscreen=False, walk=True):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="image test")
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        if fullscreen:
            self.fullscreen()
        else:
            self.set_default_size(500, 500)

        self.walk = walk
        self.files = []

        self.image = Gtk.Image()
        scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolled_window.add(self.image)
        scrolled_window.override_background_color(
            Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL,
            Gdk.RGBA(red=0, blue=0, green=0)
        )
        self.add(scrolled_window)

        self.load_image()
        self.connect('check-resize', self.on_resize)
        GLib.timeout_add_seconds(3, self.load_image)

    def on_resize(self, window):
        width, height = self.get_size()
        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(self.current_file)
        if float(width) / height > self.dimension:
            self.pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(
                self.dimension * height,
                height,
                GdkPixbuf.InterpType.NEAREST
            )
        else:
            self.pixbuf = self.pixbuf.scale_simple(
                width,
                width / self.dimension,
                GdkPixbuf.InterpType.NEAREST
            )
        GLib.idle_add(self.image.set_from_pixbuf, self.pixbuf)

    def load_image(self):
        if len(self.files) == 0:
            self.get_images()
        self.current_file = self.files.pop()
        self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file(self.current_file)
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf)

        width = self.pixbuf.get_width()
        height = self.pixbuf.get_height()
        self.dimension = float(width) / height
        return True

    def get_images(self):
        if self.walk:
            for directory, sub_directories, files in os.walk('.'):
                for filename in files:
                    if self.is_image(filename):
                        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                        self.files.append(filepath)
        else:
            for filename in os.listdir('.'):
                if self.is_image(filename):
                    self.files.append(filename)
        print('Images: {}'.format(self.files))

    def is_image(self, filename):
        return filename.split('.')[-1].lower() in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = ImageWindow()
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```